# How to run ''top'' command 1 time and exit?

Tags: command-line, top

Is there any switch to tell `top` command in order to one time scan the system and do not monitor it all time?

Comment: if you want to know something about a command, first read the man page of  corresponding command (`man command`).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `-n` switch is what you search:

```
user@host:~$ top -n 1
```

See the manpage

```
   -n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.
```

If you want to stop `top` command just press <kbd>q</kbd>.

**Notice:** If you tend to use `top` in a script, I need to say `top` is not meant for scripts, use `ps` instead.

Comment: I am using `top` in a script because I think `ps` is not capable to read CPU load average. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12):

notice that if you would like to keep "top" command for a script, you could use `-b` option ("-b" option means "batch mode operation"), this option allows you to redirect the output into a file.

Examples:

- top one shoot batch mode : `top -bn 1 2>&1 1> /tmp/topN`
- top sorted by memory usage one shoot batch mode : `top -ban 1 2>&1 1> /tmp/topAN`