# how to run the top command with 'm' already pushed?

Tags: top

I want to run top so that it opens as if you hit the m key, what I really want is this:

[How to run ''top'' command 1 time and exit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484510/how-to-run-top-command-1-time-and-exit)

But I want to

a) have the 'm' key hit
b) sort by memory (shift-m)

Can this be done from the command line?

Thanks,
Kevin

update - showing what i am seeking from command line without having to hit any key:

[image]

Just an update to clarify i need BOTH the sort by AND the memory showing, in a single command line, the given solution only solves the sort request.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want those as the *defaults*, consider using a .toprc file - see for example [How to set memory usage sort in top command as default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268933/how-to-set-memory-usage-sort-in-top-command-as-default)

Comment: 'man top' may contain the answer. Could be the -o option.

Comment: @vanadium it is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

from command line you can sort with `-o`. On MEM this would be

```
top -o +%MEM
```

if from high to low.

See `man top`:

> -o  :Override-sort-field as:  -o fieldname
> Specifies the name of the field on which  tasks  will  be  sorted,
> independent  of  what is reflected in the configuration file.  You
> can prepend a `+` or `-` to the field name to  also  override  the
> sort  direction.   A  leading  `+` will force sorting high to low,
> whereas a `-` will ensure a low to high ordering.
>
> This option exists primarily to support  automated/scripted  batch
> mode operation.

Comment: this solution solves b) but not a)

Comment: i want the output to show the memory percent graph AND ALSO sort by mem decreasing